# Why does Big-O Notation use O(1) instead of O(k)?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o, notation

If I understand Big-O notation correctly, `k` should be a constant time for the efficiency of an algorithm. Why would a constant time be considered `O(1)` rather than `O(k)`, considering it takes  a variable time? Linear growth `( O(n + k) )` uses this variable to shift the time right by a specific amount of time, so why not the same for constant complexity?

Comment: *If I understand Big-O notation correctly, k should be a constant time for the efficiency of an algorithm.*  What is `k`?

Comment: When representing linear growth, k is used, such that the complexity is O(n + k). Unless I am incorrect in saying that k is a constant time the algorithm takes?

Comment: @Simon When writing O(k) I see k is a variable, not a constant. And thus O(k) is linear time, since it's based on k. k number of operations takes k time units.

Comment: no, when representing asymptotic linear growth, it is of order O(n), where n is the variable size of input. If k is a constant, O(n + k) = O(n) asymptotically.

Comment: Ah, my mistake then. But why would O(k) be linear? It is not dependent on n at all.

Comment: Because you can name your variable whatever you want, whether it be n or k is up to you. It's just customary to use n.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such linear growth asymptotic `O(n + k)` where `k` is a constant. If `k` were a constant and you went back to the limit representation of algorithmic growth rates, you'd see that `O(n + k) = O(n)` because constants drop out in limits.

Your answer may be `O(n + k)` due to a *variable* `k` that is fundamentally independent of the other input set `n`. You see this commonly in compares vs moves in sorting algorithm analysis.

To try to answer your question about why we drop `k` in Big-O notation (which I think is taught poorly, leading to all this confusion), one definition (as I recall) of O() is as follows:

[image: formula]

```
Read: f(n) is in O( g(n) ) iff there exists d and n_0 where for all n > n_0,
                                         f(n) <= d * g(n)
```

Let's try to apply it to our problem here *where k is a constant* and thus f(x) = k and g(x) = 1.

- Is there a `d` and `n_0` that exist to satisfy these requirements?

Trivially, the answer is of course yes. Choose d > `k` and for n > 0, the definition holds.

Comment: But if k is a constant relevant to the algorithm, why use O(1) instead of O(k)?

Comment: @SImon: If `k` were constant then one would not say `O(k)`, one would say `O(1)` since they are the same thing. If `k` is not constant, but depends in some way on the input to the program, then they are not the same thing.

Comment: @SImon well, I see where you are confused. k may be relevant, but O() is only cares about *asymptotic* run times and loose equivalence. Your analysis of the algorithm may be more strict and more correct to include k as a measure of its operations

Comment: Ah, so k is just the number of operations it takes? So in that case, two algorithms of complexity O(n^2) may have a different number of operations? In that case, why would k be added to a linear complexity, rather than multiplied?

Comment: @AK4749 You can use [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WVhRA.png) definition if you like, you just need to replace your `c`s with a `d` and `x` with `n`.

Comment: @phant0m Man, I love me some imgur but it's blocked at work :( feel free to go ahead and edit my answer, I wont bite!

Comment: That's a pity. All images uploaded via SO end up on imgur. That might prove a valid reason to have it unblocked if you work in a programming related field.

Comment: @SImon Exactly, there may be and usually are many many different physical runtimes experienced by algorithms that have the same O() representation. In your case, I have no choice but to disagree with you: if the final result is O(n + k), k must be a variable that shows a different input set's influence on the algorithm than n. If k is constant, the final result of O(n + k) can be further siplified to O(n)

Comment: @SImon if k is a constant, You can indeed drop it in the situation you are describing. However, be wary, there are some situations (k^n) that require you to keep it!

Comment: @phant0m quick question, was I wrong about the magnitude requirement? (|f| <= c|g|) ? the new definition doesn't seem to require that

Comment: No, not at all. It's just that there are different definitions floating around. This is the one I was taught in my datastructures and algorithms course, and since we usually use this to talk about runtimes, the values would be positive anyway. The image defines f to be a positive function, so I thought I'd omit the `| |` from the textual description as well. I simply recycled the image from an old answer of mine.

Comment: @phant0m aha! damn the firewall, I hadn't even noticed there was an image now haha thanks

Comment: Otherwise I would not have changed the variables ;)